# SAP Fiori: Show 'My Leave Requests' in days instead of hours

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

When requesting a leave in Fiori the pop up shows the away time in hours instead of days:[image]

Is there a possiblity that instead of for example 15,00 hours the pop-up shows 2 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that many stuff in Fiori applications can also be customized by customizing your default SAP application. If your default in leave request is in hours, then that is what this Fiori app will show. Change it to days and that will be what Fiori will show.
In case you have a specific requirement to make this deviate solely in the app, then indeed you need either an extension point or create a custom implementation.

Here some additional links:

- [Preffered method](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/03/03/extend-a-fiori-application-with-sap-web-ide-part-1)
- [Old-fashioned](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-46261)

Comment: great links @Mattti.b :-)

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like, you are asking to change a standard, delivered app? 
If so, it is *only* possible to change it, if an `Extension Point` is provided at the desired place and then adapt the extended code. Check the documentation for [App Extensibility: My Leave Requests](http://help.sap.com/fiori_bs2013/helpdata/en/55/20cd5262411642e10000000a44176d/content.htm?frameset=/en/f1/9467524a916d2de10000000a44176d/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/c5/5690533e73cc26e10000000a4450e5/plain.htm&node_id=59).

In any case, if you haven't gone through the documentation for the app itself, with the possible customizations, check the [My Leave Requests Fiori app documentation](http://help.sap.com/fiori_bs2013/helpdata/en/c8/434353a531e647e10000000a441470/content.htm?frameset=/en/a1/20655213f0ea5fe10000000a423f68/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/c5/5690533e73cc26e10000000a4450e5/plain.htm&node_id=57)

Comment: Is is possible to completely replace a view or controller. This will however mean that your app cannot easily be upgraded. With the extension point that is ensured.